# SKSpritenode interacting with physic body of scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do i get a SKSpritenode to pass through the physics body of the scene unimpeded.
The properties of the node are

```
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
    monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30);
```

and the scene is

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 65), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)))
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-10);
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

At the moment when the monster node gets to the border of the scene, it will stop for a moment then continue on its path. How do i make it to it doesn't interact with the border of the scene whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to solving this problem and I would recommend you to create custom boundaries yourself instead of using the scene's physicsBody.

1) Create 4 boundaries around your scene and adjust your `collisionBitMask` and `ContactBitMask` accordingly.

2) (not tested) Adjust your `self.physicsBody` `collisionBitMask` and `contactBitMask` accordingly. This would be bad practise and could potentially cause issues with your other collisions in the future.

Comment: could you explain what accordingly is. i've gotten rid of the physics body for the scene and instead replaced with another skspritenode, but no matter how i change the properties of the two nodes, they won't freely travel through each other

Comment: For the 1st approach, you create those rects of `SKSpriteNode` with a `physicsBody`. Since you do not want to use the physics engine for collisions, make use of the contactBitMask and set it to the category that you want the node to have collisions with. This will get passed to didBeginContact.